# VSCode auto-import not working for clean angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, import, auto-import

Having a clean Angular 10 project with Typescript 3.9.7, some auto imports and suggestions are not working. For example, I begin to type FormsM... and it should appear FormsModule to autocomplete and auto import from @angular/forms, but this option does not appear. However, there are other options that do appear, for example: FormStyle (from @angular/common).

[image]

I already tried adding "typeRoots": [ "node_modules" ] to my tsconfig.json but didn't work. Is this a typescript problem or is it a vscode problem? This is killing my productivity. Please help.

I even installed a bunch of extensions but none seem to work for me. I have these enabled:

- Visual Studio IntelliCode
- TypeScript Toolbox
- TypeScript Importer
- TypeScript Hero
- TSLint
- Prettier
- Javascript (ES6) code snippets
- Angular Files

Answer (score 5):

There is a VSCode Extension call Angular Essentials. Its work for me.
[Here is the extension link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.angular-essentials)