# Intellisense/autoImport/importSuggestions not working in angular/vsCode/typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am having trouble with auto importing `node_modules` in angular, vsCode

Expected behaviour:
When i start typing a name of an installed module in my angular typescript files, for instance "MatMenuM" or "HttpCl", a suggestion for an import should appear.

Current behaviour:
The correct suggestion does not appear

[image: matMenuModule suggestion fail]

[image: httpclient suggestion fail]

My environment:
Fresh angular project on windows 10 with newest(28.03.2022) versions of angular cli, node, typescript, vsCode, only two extensions, all up-to-date, and imported newest angular material.

[image: angular version]

[image: tsconfig.json]

[image: tsconfig.app.json]

[image: extensions all up-to-date]

[image: angular.json 1]

[image: angular.json 2]

[image: package.json]

[image: import settings]

I realize that this question has been asked a couple of times, but none of the answers solve my problem. Also the angular and ts versions might be different. I will link all related questions below. I also tried all of the suggested solutions:

I tried:

- adding `typeRoots` in my `tsconfig.json`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55082763/vscode-intellisense-doesnt-suggest-angular-modules-until-imported-manually-in-t), all i got was this:

[image: typeroot issue with cli]

Also this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16879) related to the same problem sais the issue should be fixed with the new ts version... which it isn't for me.

- setting my preferred pathstyle for auto imports to relative, shortest, project-relative and non-relative
- uninstalling angular, node, vsCode and ts and reinstalling it
- removing all extensions
- removing `types: []` from my `tsconfig.app.json`
- adding `"node_modules/@angular/**/*.d.ts"` to include in my `tsconfig.app.json`

Related questions:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66859662/vscode-is-somehow-not-registering-angular-modules-and-gives-false-errors), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48214123/having-trouble-to-autocomplete-and-auto-import-while-developing-on-angular), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63638651/vscode-auto-import-not-working-for-clean-angular-project), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55082763/vscode-intellisense-doesnt-suggest-angular-modules-until-imported-manually-in-t), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67171878/typescript-autocomplete-autoimport-not-working-in-angular-project-subfolders)

Help will be much appreciated!

Edits: images not formatted correctly, spelling

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved my problem:

VsCode does not autosuggest modules out of the box, even with older versions as far as i can tell.
I was under the misconception that it did, since in my work project, suggestions work fine, however now i realize that was only because:

VsCode needs the module to be imported at least once (doesn't matter where) to suggest it everywhere.

So you have to import it once, then vsCode starts suggestions, which means only one time pain.

Still setting up a new project can be tedeous that way, i will use webstorm(suggests everything out of the box) as a setup IDE, then if my project as enough imports, i can still switch back to vsCode.

Comment: I too faced same issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75131078/can-not-do-auto-imports-by-merely-mentioning-them-in-imports-array-in-angular-en

I figured out whenever a module is in subfolder, it is not auto suggested. However if it is not in subfolder it does get auto suggested. Do you have any idea why `rxjs` Obserable import does'nt get auto suggested?

For me comming from `java` `eclipse` environment it is sure a pain. Its hard to belive if there are dependencies available in `node_modules` then why intellisense not work for them.